# Rule based System vs. Fuzzy systems

Tags: artificial-intelligence

What is the significance of using a rule-based system and a fuzzy expert system? Also, what is the difference between them? I have attempted to go over the lecture slides for my class however I still do not understand.

Answer (score 1):

Rule-based is largely "If....Then".

Fuzzy is varying degrees of "0......1" basically.

Former does not scale well and is considered dated by many.  Latter has been around for decades and tends to be too ambiguous, difficult to rely on in logic/decision paths.